# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes minutes after startup

Tags: 18.04, freeze

The issue appeared around a week ago and persists on a fresh install. It also keeps freezing on the live usb Ubuntu demo. The PC will crash on its own eventually (takes a minute or two, most of the time), but trying to play a video will cause it to crash as soon as it's opened. So it might be a GPU issue? (Works fine on Windows, though.)
Specs are an AMD R9 390 GPU and i5-4590, in case that's relevant.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! The cause can be anything! Care to share some errors you get? Maybe edit the answer and post relevant lines from `dmesg` output, `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log`.

Comment: @MrShunz I doubt I can keep the PC on long enough to open/post anything.